# I have a problem with optional parameters that gives 404 error in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-7, php-7.1, modulenotfounderror

I have the following function in laravel 7:

```
public function create(Franchise $franchise = null)
{
  ...
}
```

And the route is as follows:

```
Route::get('series/create/{franchise?}', 'SerieController@create')->name('serie.create');
```

when I execute it with parameters for example `page_name/series/create/1` it executes normally but when I execute without parameters `page_name/series/create` I get an error `404 | Not Found`.

I also used `dd()` at the beginning of the function and it keeps giving me the same error

I also did the same with index:

```
Route::get('series/{franchise?}', 'SerieController@index')->name('serie');
```

And there it executes me well with or without parameters
Is there a route problem?

Comment: try changing the order of those 2 routes?

Comment: What is page_name ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you didn't add `/series/create` to your router. This is the reason why Laravel doesn't see this route and throws a 404 error. Add that route to your router file: